# Arduino Curly Braces without statement

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I was reading the following [sample code](https://github.com/monstrenyatko/ArduinoMqtt/blob/master/examples/ConnectEsp8266WiFiClient/ConnectEsp8266WiFiClient.ino) and I noticed the use of curly braces without any statement inside `loop()`:

```
// Start new MQTT connection
MqttClient::ConnectResult connectResult;
// Connect
{
  MQTTPacket_connectData options = MQTTPacket_connectData_initializer;
  options.MQTTVersion = 4;
  options.clientID.cstring = (char*)MQTT_ID;
  options.cleansession = true;
  options.keepAliveInterval = 15; // 15 seconds
  MqttClient::Error::type rc = mqtt->connect(options, connectResult);
  if (rc != MqttClient::Error::SUCCESS) {
    LOG_PRINTFLN("Connection error: %i", rc);
    return;
  }
}
```

Right below `// Connect` there is the curly brace in question. I understabd that curly braces are used to encapsulate code within an if statement, a loop, a function block, etc. What is the meaning of the curly braces used in the sample code? I tried removing the curly braces in question and the sketch would compile just fine. So what is the difference or purpose of these curly braces?

Comment: It limits the scope of any local variables (`options`, in this case) to just the block.  The `options` here becomes an entirely separate variable from any other `options` within the function.  It also ensures that `options` is destroyed by the end of the block, rather than perhaps lingering around until the end of the entire function.

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces server several purposes in C-based languages (e.g. to hold an `if` block, as you're doing), but the first and last ones here simply **define a local scope**.  In this exact case, these can be removed without problems because there's nothing else to separate into different scopes.  **However** if you had more code that followed, as you probably do or will, any local variables defined inside this local scope (e.g. `options`) would be invisible to stuff defined outside this local scope.